# Linebreak in style.Text in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I have a vector layer from json, and have a style symbolizer:

```
new ol.style.Text({
  text: ol.expr.parse('name')
})
```

In an vector layer, some of the nodes contains more than one name. I try to find a way to split the names on lines.

- Openlayers seems to ignore '\n' in the json.
- I can't find a way to edit the string, for example with replace(re, "\n")

Comment: Is Openlayers v3 officially released now? from the blog is seems to be in alpha 4 status currently http://openlayers.org/blog/

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be very hard to do at this time.

The obstacle is that the Openlayers vector renderer uses the canvas function textfill(), which does not support multiline text. The '\n' is ignored by this function.

The solutions for this on a general basis is to create a textfill-element for each line, like in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BaG4J/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the stringDivider method in the source code for this example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html